# Why are sudo privileges lost running install script for CLI?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

Note: I ultimately got things working- namely install a CLI (Tenderly), but I want to know why it didn't work the normal way, and so prevent future frustrations when the pressure is on.

The prescribed way:
`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tenderly/tenderly-cli/master/scripts/install-macos.sh | sh`

Error

```
➜  ~ sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tenderly/tenderly-cli/master/scripts/install-linux.sh | sh 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1151  100  1151    0     0   1859      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1856
Installing version 1.4.5
Moving CLI to /usr/local/bin/
mv: cannot move 'tenderly' to '/usr/local/bin/tenderly': Permission denied
Tenderly CLI installed to: 
sh: 41: tenderly: not found
New Tenderly version installed: 
➜  ~ ls /usr/local/bin/tenderly
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/tenderly': No such file or directory
```

That includes calling curl with and without sudo.

I then ran these commands:

```
➜  ~ touch temp
➜  ~ mv temp /usr/local/bin
mv: cannot move 'temp' to '/usr/local/bin/temp': Permission denied
➜  ~ sudo mv temp /usr/local/bin #okay
```

Why does sudo work in one case and not the other? Does curl or that script spawn a new process that loses sudo privileges?

I got it installed by downloading the script as a file and running that.

```
> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tenderly/tenderly-cli/master/scripts/install-macos.sh > install.sh
> sudo install.sh
```

Comment: If you put an "inspect" step in the middle, you'll be happier/safer. `less install.sh` is easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one does the deprecated, unsafe, insecure command:

```
sudo somecommand | sh
```

only `somecommand` is run as `root`, its `STDOUT` is piped to `sh`, which is run as `$USER`.
This is probably a copying error from the past. The effective, although insecure and unsafe is:

```
somecommand | sudo sh
```

A safer, more secure way is:

```
somecommand >install.sh
# Read the file, figure out what it does
less -Mersj4 install.sh
# if you like what install.sh does 
# Maybe`sudo apt install watchinstall` 
# and run this under `installwatch`
sudo ./install.sh
```

Trust, but verify.

Comment: What the `-Mersj4 ` options for `less` do? `M` seems to make it prompt more, `-e` will make it exit when you reach the end of the file (which would be surprising behavior as the file will suddenly disappear), `-r` is actually actively warned against in `man less` (did you mean `-R`?), `-s` could be handy although it will make the script harder to use, and `-j4` just makes you not able to search the first 3 lines of the file. Surely `less install.sh` would be a better choice!